# ZFS install on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: apt, zfs

I've recently upgraded my Home server form 14.04LTS to 16.04 LTS. ZFS was working fine and the box was succesfuly serving out my samba share and acting as a KODI server and end user (I was succesfully running the SQL database and had multiple nodes around the house).

Perhaps I did it wrong, but after the restart ZFS was no longer up and running and I've had to try to reinstall it.  I've tried following all the information that I can online to no avail.  Below is the input and output that I get.

All help prethanked.

```
sudo apt install zfs

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zfsutils-linux' instead of 'zfs'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
zfsutils-linux :

Depends: zfs-doc (= 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu14) but 0.6.5.7-1~trusty is to be installed

Depends: libnvpair1linux but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libuutil1linux but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libzfs2linux but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libzpool2linux but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: zfs-zed but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you use some kind of ppa for zfs? It is trying to install a trusty version of zfs-doc.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, you have broken dependencies, this is why zfs won't install. Do you still have zfs ppa active? Get rid of them by removing the ppa with the update manager.

With 16.04LTS, zfs is in the standard install.

Use `sudo apt clean`, then `sudo apt update` for a fresh start. Do a `apt purge zfs*` next, but **make sure that nothing else besides zfs gets removed!**

`sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux` is all you need to reinstall zfs. Make sure to import your old pool by `zpool import mypoolname`, use the -f switch if it wasn't exported before.