# How do I get ZFS working after upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, zfs

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 just recently and in the process my ZFS stopped working.  I was previously using ZFS packages from a PPA, but I have followed the directions to remove/purge them here: [ZFS install on Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842316/zfs-install-on-ubuntu-16-04lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

After the install I get an error when running an ZFS command:

```
:~$ sudo zfs get all
The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
```

If I try to follow the directions I get the following error:

```
:~$ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Invalid argument
```

When I reinstall ZFS I get some errors, but I'm not sure if these are related to my problem?

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc zfs-zed
Suggested packages:
  zfs-initramfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 897 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,902 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfs-doc all 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [50.1 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libuutil1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [27.5 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnvpair1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [23.4 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzpool2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [384 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzfs2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [106 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfsutils-linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [276 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfs-zed amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16 [29.8 kB]
Fetched 897 kB in 0s (2,402 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-doc.
(Reading database ... 172013 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-doc_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_all.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-doc (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuutil1linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libuutil1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuutil1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvpair1linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzpool2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libzpool2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzpool2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzfs2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libzfs2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzfs2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfsutils-linux.
Preparing to unpack .../zfsutils-linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-zed.
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-zed_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-zed (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up zfs-doc (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Setting up libuutil1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Setting up libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Setting up libzpool2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Setting up libzfs2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'plexmediaserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plexmediaserver'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
zfs-import-cache.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-mount.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
Setting up zfs-zed (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16) ...
zed.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help from this post fixed my problem: [Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade broke my ZFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910828/ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04-upgrade-broke-my-zfs/912676#912676)

I'm not sure what actually fixed it this time, but here's a list of the things I tried before it started working.  My pool was mounted without even a reboot!

```
apt clean
apt update
apt purge zfs*
apt-get remove spl dkms spl-dkms
apt-get autoremove
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable

apt-get install zfsutils-linux
apt-get install spl-dkms
```

Comment: +1 Exactly this fixed it for me.  After 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade ZFS was not automatically loading the module nor automounting.  Thank you.