# Upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS broke ZFS

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, zfs

I have delayed the update of my file server from 14.04LTS which I did yesterday. That upgrade totally broke ZFS.

I have tried everything I found on this site, like:

- [ZFS install on Ubuntu 16.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842316/zfs-install-on-ubuntu-16-04lts)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade broke my ZFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910828/ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04-upgrade-broke-my-zfs/912676#912676)

I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable
sudo apt clean
```

Then: `apt-get install zfsutils-linux`
returns:

```
zfsutils-linux is already the newest version (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28).
```

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zfs-zed : Depends: libnvpair1linux but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libzfs2linux but it is not going to be installed
 zfsutils-linux : Depends: libnvpair1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libuutil1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzfs2linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzpool2linux but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).'
```

So I try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And now I get:

```
After this operation, 1,775 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libuutil1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28 [27.4 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnvpair1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28 [23.5 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzpool2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28 [384 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzfs2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28 [107 kB]
Fetched 542 kB in 0s (636 kB/s)   
(Reading database ... 1279402 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../libuutil1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuutil1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libuutil1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/lib/libuutil.so.1.0.1', which is also in package libuutil1 0.6.5.4-1~precise

Preparing to unpack .../libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/lib/libnvpair.so.1.0.1', which is also in package libnvpair1 0.6.5.4-1~precise

Preparing to unpack .../libzpool2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libzpool2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libzpool2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/lib/libzpool.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libzpool2 0.6.5.4-1~precise

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Preparing to unpack .../libzfs2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libzfs2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libzfs2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/lib/libzfs.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libzfs2 0.6.5.4-1~precise

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libuutil1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libzpool2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libzfs2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

```
dpkg -l | grep -i "zfs"

rc  libzfs1                                                     0.6.2-1~precise                                 amd64        Native ZFS filesystem library for Linux
ii  libzfs2                                                     0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS filesystem library for Linux
rc  libzpool1                                                   0.6.2-1~precise                                 amd64        Native ZFS pool library for Linux
ii  libzpool2                                                   0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS pool library for Linux
rc  ubuntu-zfs                                                  8~precise                                       amd64        Native ZFS filesystem metapackage for Ubuntu.
rc  zfs-auto-snapshot                                           1.0.8-0ubuntu1~precise1                         all         ZFS Automatic Snapshot Service
ii  zfs-dkms                                                    0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28                               amd64        Native OpenZFS filesystem kernel modules for Linux
ii  zfs-doc                                                     0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28                               all          Native OpenZFS filesystem documentation and examples.
iU  zfs-zed                                                     0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28                               amd64        OpenZFS Event Daemon (zed)
rc  zfsutils                                                    0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS management utilities for Linux
iU  zfsutils-linux                                              0.6.5.6-0ubuntu28                               amd64        Native OpenZFS management utilities for Linux
```

---

OK, some improvements, through a combination of `dpkg`, `apt` and `apt-get` commands I was able to remove the dependency errors.

NOW, the issue is something that has been documented but the solutions haven't helped me.

First I did this:
reboot

```
apt clean
apt update
apt purge zfs*
apt-get remove spl dkms spl-dkms
apt-get autoremove

reboot

sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux zfs-initramfs spl-dkms
```

(I added zfs-initramfs because it was suggested)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux spl zfs-dkms zfs-doc zfs-zed
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux spl spl-dkms zfs-dkms zfs-doc zfs-initramfs zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,456 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

......
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.13.0-181-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-181-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.5.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

What do I do now? Do I have a kernel issue?

Comment: BTW, do you see the "overwrite" errors above? Like: libzpool2 0.6.5.4-1~precise. Does it mean that I have remnants of 14.04LTS?

Comment: I believe you have to remove the existing ones that it's trying to overwrite first before installing the new ones.  You might have to remove them one by one, then do the installation again.

Comment: What would be a "benign" way of removing those? I am afraid of breaking other dependencies.....

Comment: I wish I knew.  The last time I bumped into something like this I had to do it one by one and any of the other dependencies that it wanted to autoremove I added to a list and just ran a `sudo apt install --reinstall <package name>` to keep the dependencies there to remove them from the list of being no longer needed.  It's too bad you can't do `sudo apt install --reinstall <package name>` for the ones here that it wants to overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

I did have a kernel issue. I didn't realize that the updater didn't touch the kernel. When I updated to 4.+, all problems went away! Whew...